# Cannot connect to google directions API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-directions-api

I am trying to use Google Directions API using an Android Application.

On the google developer console, I created a project and selected the Android platform.

Using my unique package name and SHA1 key, I got an API key.

In my android code, I am using this API key to send an HTTP request.

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Dhanmondi&destination="+destination+"&key=" + apiKey;



public String sendGetRequest(String uri) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String result;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((result = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(result);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, I am getting this error.

**This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 112.13.34.221 with empty referrer.**

I have enabled Google Maps for Android API as well as Google Directions, Google Roads and Google Places API

[image]

Comment: Have you added the same package name during key creation, have you enabled directions api, and have added the key in the manifest

Comment: I have everything you mentioned @war_Hero

Comment: what is the error status code that is returned , also if you paste the url in browser tab check if you get the response

Comment: The status code is 403 ... I have edited my question providing the screenshot ... and the URL does not work in browser because I selected android platform while creating my project @war_Hero

Comment: it is something to do with the url parsing

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have given the package name right while creating the api key.

have you created a android key or a server key or a browser key .? make sure you have created android key .
direction api require android key.

make sure you have enabled the direction api in google console for your api key.

keep in mind all these points while doing the api creation and let us know what happens next.

thank you

Comment: I followed all the steps you described, but still same error @Sagar Nayak

Answer (score 0):

This type of error usually comes when you not enable your Api on Google console. So please make your Api enable on Console. ([Google API Key issues with Google Places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955629/google-api-key-issues-with-google-places))

If your request is malformed or supplies an invalid signature, the Google Maps Directions API returns an HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error. ([Troubleshooting authentication issues](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key#troubleshooting-authentication-issues))